Histograms and plots?
I have question regarding the posted plot. This is a plot of inter-arrival times of order flow at a stock exchange. I want to know if people know how to generate this plot. I can generate a histogram. I can also plot a density. I am not sure how they generated this plot. If anyone knows I would like to know how to generate one of these.

